# Ranger ascendancies - Deadeye vs Raider

Tags: path-of-exile

Excluding Pathfinder evaluation since (afaik) that is highly dependent on good flasks and using them a lot. Between the other 2, what factors are important to picking them?

A lot of the Raider benefits are also present in 'lite' form on the tree or jewels, like Onslaught or Phasing buffs; and many skills for Frenzy such as Blood Rage. Conversely, Ranger has ailment immunity (Avatar of Veil) which Deadeye cannot get.

My current build is physical dps with some bleed/poison chance, I might end up using Crimson Storm and going for Deadeye (for Rupture). But other than the obvious cases like TS, BA, bleed builds going for Deadeye; what to look for when deciding on an ascendancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Raider* and *Deadeye* have many differences, for instance:

**Raider**
Raiders focus on high speed (movement, attack, and cast) thanks to Frenzy Charger and/or Onslaught and have a nice bonus to Phasing, that make this class a good all-round class.

**Deadeye**
Deadeye is a class dedicated to the Projectile tag. Nearly all the points of the class interacts with skills (both Attacks and Spell) which have Projectiles with multiple bonus: Pierce, Fork, Chain, and Additional Projectiles. It also has some specific boosts for Attacks, like the increased global Accuracy Rating.

*When to choose Raider?*
You chose Raider if you want a generic-DPS class that focuses on speed, more than anything else.

*When to choose Deadeye?*
If you want to augment Projectile-type skills.

I've tried to keep it as general as possible, as for PoE every class can be played in thousands of different ways thanks to the unique interactions between skills and items. Consider that a general "rule of thumb".